# Error while implementing a subscript defined in a Protocol in Swift

Tags: cocoa, swift, protocols

I have the following protocol, with 1 var and 2 subscripts:

```
protocol Universe{

    var count: Int{get}

    subscript(heroAtIndex index: Int)->SuperPowered {get}
    subscript(villainAtIndex index: Int)->SuperPowered {get}

}
```

While trying to implement this protocol in this class:

```
class Marvel: Universe{

    var _heroes = [
    SuperPowered.heroWithFirstName("Peter", lastName: "Parker", alias: "Spiderman"),
    SuperPowered.heroWithFirstName("Scott", lastName: "Summers", alias: "Cyclops"),
    SuperPowered.heroWithFirstName("Ororo", lastName: "Monroe", alias: "Storm")]

    var _villains = [
    SuperPowered.villainWithFirstName("Victor", lastName: "Von Doom", alias: "Dr Doom"),
    SuperPowered.villainWithFirstName("Erik", lastName: "Lehnsher", alias: "Magneto"),
    SuperPowered.villainWithFirstName("Cain", lastName: "Marko", alias: "Juggernaut")]

    // UNiverse protocol

    var count : Int{
        get{
            return _heroes.count + _villains.count
        }
    }

    subscript(heroAtIndex index: Int)->SuperPowered{
        return _heroes[index]
    }
}
```

I get an error on the las line (the subscript). It complains that

```
method 'subscript(heroAtIndex:)' has different argument names from those required by protocol 'Universe' ('subscript(villainAtIndex:)')
        subscript(heroAtIndex index: Int)->SuperPowered{
        ^
```

I have no idea what the compiler is talking about: the names ARE the same and I even copied and pasted.

What's going on?

Comment: Guys, can you believe the error goes away as soon as I implement BOTH of the subscripts? As long as only one is implemented, it fails with that crazy error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments can either be named or positional. By putting `heroAtIndex index` you're making it a named argument; i.e. you have to call `subscript(heroAtIndex:x)`

You then have the problem that these two methods have exactly the same name and argument types.  It's getting confused and because you're only implementing one of them, it's complaining that when trying to find the implementation of the other one that you got the argument names wrong.

When you implement both of them (as your protocol says you should) there is no longer a compile time error, so the problem goes away as does the error message.

Comment: I ran into exactly the same problem, and spent half an hour trying to figure out what was wrong. Since implementing the first of my two methods broke code completion for the second, I never ended up adding the second, and thus realizing nothing was wrong. Oh Xcode!